# button color change to indicate visitor is on current page in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently trying to make the button to change background color to let the visitor know which page they are currently on. Anyone know how to do that? I've only managed to make it change color upon clicking.
I'm using react router in reactJS and for example i have 2 buttons, home and about, if im on home, the button colour will be blue, while the about button colour will be orange, and same goes otherwise, if im on about page, then the button will be blue and the home button will be orange.
but currently i can only manage the change color on click

```
    const [btnClass, setBtnClass] = useState('blue-color');

  function toggleColor() {
    if (btnClass === 'blue-color') {
        setBtnClass('orange-color');
    } else {
        setBtnClass('blue-color');
    }
}

  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="nav">
      <button
  onClick={() => {
    navigateHome();
    toggleColor();
  }}
  className={`${btnClass} po-btn`}>Home</button>
<button
  onClick={() => {
    navigateToAbout();
    toggleColor();
  }}
  className={`${btnClass} pr-btn`}>About</button>

        <Routes>
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if I am guessing right you want to show highlighted color when a user is on the About page for example what you can do is change the route url when the user go to the About page and get the current route details in `useEffect` with `window.location.pathname` to get the path and manipulate the color

Comment: can i use active for it? im still new to reactJS so i dont really know window.location.pathname

Answer (score 0):

```js
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import {
  Stack,
  Typography,
  Tabs,
  Tab
} from '@mui/material'

const LinkTab = props => {
  return (
    <Tab
      component={Link}
      onClick={event => {
        event.preventDefault()
      }}
      {...props}
    />
  )
}

const MenuButtons = props => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0)

  const handleItemClick = (event, index) => {
    setSelectedIndex(index)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const findCurrentPathname = () => {
      if (location.pathname === '/') {
        setSelectedIndex(0)
      }
      if (location.pathname === '/home') {
        setSelectedIndex(0)
      }
      if (location.pathname === '/about') {
        setSelectedIndex(1)
      }
    }
    findCurrentPathname()
  }, [selectedIndex, location]) 

  return ( 
   <React.Fragment>
      <Tabs
        value={selectedIndex}
        aria-label='nav tabs example'
        orientation='vertical'
        visibleScrollbar={false}
        TabIndicatorProps={{
          style: { display: 'none' }
        }}
        >
         <LinkTab
            label={
              <Stack
                direction='row'
                alignItems='center'
                alignSelf='flex-start'
                gap={1}
              >
                <Typography
                  variant='body1'
                >
                  Home
                </Typography>
              </Stack>
            }
            className='menuBtn'
            key='Home'
            to={'/'}
            onClick={e => handleItemClick(e, 0)}
          />  
         <LinkTab
            label={
              <Stack
                direction='row'
                alignItems='center'
                alignSelf='flex-start'
                gap={1}
              >
                <Typography
                  variant='body1'
                >
                  About
                </Typography>
              </Stack>
            }
            className='menuBtn'
            key='About'
            to={'/about'}
            onClick={e => handleItemClick(e, 1)}
          />
      </Tabs>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/about" element={ < About /> } />
        <Route path="/" element={ < Home /> } />
      </Routes>
   </React.Fragment>
  )
 }
```

```css
/* Selected menu button color */
.menuBtn.Mui-selected {
  background: #1d5fff !important;
  color: #f9fdff !important;
}

/* Default menu button color */
.menuBtn {
  background: #f48225 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

I would suggest to use [MUI](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/) framework for the menu buttons combined with Link from react-route-dom.
In useEffect you can check the location.pathname (through react-route-dom useLocation) and update the selectedIndex of the Tabs.
Then, in the CSS, the menu items will change background colors based on the selectedIndex.